# Android get sharedPreferences to store user choices

Tags: android, variables, drawable, sharedpreferences

I want to display the the fruit of choice as a drawable
i have it so that it saves but I don't know how to get it from the activity preference 
and use it

I was thinking there might be somthing like fruit = getpreference (something like this)

```
int resourceID = getResource.getIdentifier(fruit,"drawable",getPackageName());

favortieFruit.setImageResource(resourceID);
```

Options.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Options extends PreferenceActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.options);
        //Get the custom preference
        Preference customPref = (Preference) findPreference("listPref");
        customPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

                SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("Fruits", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference.edit();

                editor.commit();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Options.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <PreferenceCategory
                android:title="Fruit Selection" android:key="listPref">
                <ListPreference android:title="Fruit #1" android:key="listPref1" android:defaultValue="digiGreen" android:entries="@array/Fruits" android:entryValues="@array/listValues" android:summary="Select Fruit #1 "/><ListPreference
                        android:title="Fruit #2"
                        android:summary="Select Fruit #2 "
                        android:key="listPref2"
                        android:defaultValue="digiGreen"
                        android:entries="@array/Fruits"
                        android:entryValues="@array/listValues" /><ListPreference
                        android:title="Fruit #3"
                        android:key="listPref3"
                        android:defaultValue="digiGreen"
                        android:entries="@array/Fruits"
                        android:entryValues="@array/listValues" android:summary="Select Fruit #3 "/><ListPreference
                        android:title="Fruit #4"
                        android:key="listPref4"
                        android:defaultValue="digiGreen"
                        android:entries="@array/Fruits"
                        android:entryValues="@array/listValues" android:summary="Select Fruit #4 "/><ListPreference
                        android:title="Fruit #5"
                        android:key="listPref5"
                        android:defaultValue="digiGreen"
                        android:entries="@array/Fruits"
                        android:entryValues="@array/listValues" android:summary="Select Fruit #5 "/><ListPreference
                        android:title="Fruit #6"
                        android:key="listPref6"
                        android:defaultValue="digiGreen"
                        android:entries="@array/Fruits"
                        android:entryValues="@array/listValues" android:summary="Select Fruit #6 "/>
        </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="Fruits">
   <item>Apple</item>
   <item>Pear</item>
   <item>Grape</item>
      <item >Berry</item>
        <item >Tomato</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="listValues">
   <item>apple</item>
   <item>pear</item>
   <item>grape</item>
   <item>berry</item>
   <item>tomato</item>
</string-array>
```

==============================
Found the solution

Options.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Options extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    }
}
```

Getting the settings

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        for (int num = 1; num < 7; num++) {

            String icon = sp.getString("listPref" + num, null);

            try {
                Class<drawable> res = R.drawable.class;
                Field field = res.getField(icon);
                PoliticiansArray[num] = field.getInt(null);
                Class<string> stringRes = R.string.class;
                Field stringField = stringRes.getField(icon);
                SayingsArray[num] = stringField.getInt(null);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MyTag", "Failed", e);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `PreferenceChangeListener` to your `ListPreference`

This is an example of how to get the newly selected value from a `ListPreference`:

```
final ListPreference myPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("listPref");
    myPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        // @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                Object newValue) {
            SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("Fruits", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference.edit();
            editor.putString("favfruit", (String) newValue);
            editor.commit();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

When you want to get back the value you saved on SharedPreferences, do it like this:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Fruits", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
String fruit= settings.getString("favfruit",null);
```

Then, get your drawable:

```
int resourceID = getResource.getIdentifier(fruit,"drawable",getPackageName());
favortieFruit.setImageResource(resourceID);
```

Comment: OK one last thing what is the zero for SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Fruits", 0); is it to move through 0 to 5 ? I'm new to android coding started 7 days ago

Comment: That is about permissions, check it out here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

However, if you want multiple fruit selection.... you should use several ListPreference's... and not a single one...

Comment: I added the example code to my program and changed listPref to listPref1 Fruits to Fruit1 all the other setting still save why is this should not only the first one save?

Comment: I am having some trouble understanding what you really want... You should really add some punctuation to your sentences... Nevertheless, if you want to select more than one fruit, you should have more than on ListPreference in your xml.

Comment: OK thanks. I ended up not using any of this code or my code. but this did help me to get there. I will post my code here in a few days maybe it will help some one.

Comment: here is what I was working on https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ice_os.android.pound_a_politician